# How to move from std::optional<T>

Tags: c++, std, c++14, boost-optional

Consider the following example where we parse data and pass the result to the next function:

```
Content Parse(const std::string& data);
void Process(Content content);

int main()
{
    auto data = ReadData();
    Process(Parse(data));    
}
```

Now let's change the code using `std::optional` to handle a failed parsing step:

```
optional<Content> Parse(const std::string& data);
void Process(Content content);

int main()
{
    auto data = ReadData();
    auto content = Parse(data);
    if (content)
        Process(move(*content));
}
```

Is it valid to move from `optional<T>::value()`? If it's ok for `std::optional` is it valid for `boost::optional` as well?

Comment: I would think this would be fine.  The contained value should be in a valid but unspecified state after moving from it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is valid to move from `optional<T>::value()` since it returns a mutable reference and the move does not destroy the object. If the `optional` instance is not *engaged*, `value()` will throw a `bad_optional_access` exception (§20.6.4.5).

You explicitly check whether the option is engaged:

```
if (content)
    Process(move(*content));
```

But you don't use the member `value()` to access the underlying `T`. Note that `value()` performs a check internally before returning a valid `T&`, unlike `operator*` which has a **precondition** that the `optional` instance shall be engaged. This is a subtle difference, but you use the right idiom:

```
if (o)
  f(*o)
```

as opposed to

```
if (o)  // redundant check
  f(o.value())
```

In Boost, the situation is a little different: first, there exists no member function called `value()` that provides checked access. (A `bad_optional_access` exception simply does not exist). The member `get()` is just an alias for `operator*` and always relies on the user checking that the `optional` instance is engaged.

Comment: Does `operator*` have a rvalue reference overload?  Ie, `f( *std::move(o) )` -- does that move?  I hope so!

Comment: I couldn't find one in [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf). Have a look at §20.6.4 on page 505 where the interface is described.

Comment: Hmm.  `value_or` has a `&&` and `&` overload.  `value` does not (Why not?  Naively, it should).  I could see not wanting a `&&` `operator*` in case people are tempted to `*` without checking if the `optional` is engaged first, but with the throwing `value` I cannot see the harm?

Comment: Looking at a newer C++17 standard draft (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) and && observer is already there. See page 557.

Comment: *engaged* confused me, the standard uses the phrase *contains a value* instead.

Answer (score -1):

For your current implementation the answer is NO. But if you slightly change it you'll be able to move the value. There are 4 overloads for optional's operator * (as well as for method *value()*). And there are just 2 of them returning rvalue reference (*_Ty &&* and *const _Ty &&*) to encapsulated value. But they have signature *&&* and *const &&* respectively. It means you can use them only if your optional variable itself is accessed by rvalue reference. In this case the implementation should look like:

```
std::optional<Content> Parse(const std::string& data);
void Process(Content content);

int main()
{
    auto data = ReadData();
    auto content = Parse(data);
    if (content)
        Process(*std::move(content));
}
```